# How to manipulate a URL string in order to extract a single piece?

Tags: python, string, parsing, split, str-replace

I'm new to programming and Python.

**Background**

My program accepts a url. I want to extract the username from the url.

The username is the subdomain. 
If the subdomain is 'www', the username should be the main part of the domain. The rest of the domain should be discard (eg. '.com/', '.org/')

I've tried the following:

```
def get_username_from_url(url):
    if url.startswith(r'http://www.'):
        user = url.replace(r'http://www.', '', 1)
        user = user.split('.')[0]
        return user
    elif url.startswith(r'http://'):
        user = url.replace(r'http://', '', 1)
        user = user.split('.')[0]
        return user

easy_url = "http://www.httpwwwweirdusername.com/"    
hard_url = "http://httpwwwweirdusername.blogger.com/"

print get_username_from_url(easy_url)
# output = httpwwwweirdusername (good! expected.)

print get_username_from_url(hard_url)
# output = weirdusername (bad! username should = httpwwwweirdusername)
```

I've tried many other combinations using `strip()`, `split()`, and `replace()`.

Could you advise me on how to solve this relatively simple problem?

Comment: have you tried using string patterns and strpos() ... seems like they can help you in your problem

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible to do this with regular expressions (could probably modify the regex to be more accurate/efficient).

```
import re
url_pattern = re.compile(r'.*/(?:www.)?(\w+)')
def get_username_from_url(url):
    match = re.match(url_pattern, url)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)

easy_url = "http://www.httpwwwweirdusername.com/"
hard_url = "http://httpwwwweirdusername.blogger.com/"

print get_username_from_url(easy_url)
print get_username_from_url(hard_url)
```

Which yields us:

```
httpwwwweirdusername
httpwwwweirdusername
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a module called [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) that is specifically for the task:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> url = "http://httpwwwweirdusername.blogger.com/"
>>> urlparse(url).hostname.split('.')[0]
'httpwwwweirdusername'
```

In case of `http://www.httpwwwweirdusername.com/` it would output `www` which is not desired. There are workarounds to ignore `www` part, like, for example, get the first item from the splitted `hostname` that is not equal to `www`:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse

>>> url = "http://www.httpwwwweirdusername.com/"
>>> next(item for item in urlparse(url).hostname.split('.') if item != 'www')
'httpwwwweirdusername'

>>> url = "http://httpwwwweirdusername.blogger.com/"
>>> next(item for item in urlparse(url).hostname.split('.') if item != 'www')
'httpwwwweirdusername'
```